# How to kill a foregound service

Tags: android, service, persistent, foreground

I am developping an app that requires the use of a foreground service. The service does its job properly but i can't kill it. First, I tried to kill by using stopService, then i saw a topic where people said to use startService with an extra as a key to kill the service :

In my activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
i.putBooleanExtra("killService",true);
```

In my service's onStartCommand:

```
if(intent.getBooleanExtra("killService",false))
{
    stopForeground(true);
    stopSelf();
 ....
```

I want to stop the service when the user presses a specific button of my activity :

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch(v.getId)
    {
       case R.id.myButton:
       (here i want to kill the service)
       break;
       ...
```

Comment: You may need to pay attention to the fact that there is a difference between informing Android that you no longer *require* something, vs. actually *killing* its process - something that in 99% of cases you *should not* be trying to do, but rather let Android decide to do if/when it needs to re-use the resources held by the process.

Comment: Sorry, i dont want to kill the service but i want to stop it and make sure that onDestroy is being called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, onDestroy was being called but i wasnt able to see it...

Answer (score 0):

If your service is not intended for "*binding*" to any of your clients, then explicit `stopService(Intent)` call would be enough to kill your service

If your service is intended for binding and you have successfully bound to service via a call to `bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int)`, you have to call `unbindService(..)` from your bound clients.

If your service supports both binding and starting, you'll have to use hybrid approach to stop it.

1. **Bound Service**: To stop a previously [bound](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29) service, you have to unbind **all the clients** you have previously bound your service to.
2. **Started service**: To stop a service started with `startService(Intent)`, you have to call `stopService(Intent)`. That would be enough, no need to start it with any command.
3. **Mixed (Bound and Started) Service**: You have to explicitly call `stopService(Intent)` and unbind all the clients. Only when all your  clients are unbound from service and `stopService(Intent)` has been called, the service will actually stop.

If you are not sure what kind of service you have, read [Services guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), explanation there is satisfactory.

Comment: My service is not bound but stopService doesn't work

Comment: show the relevant part of code, where you attempt to stop a service

Comment: How do you understand your service is not killed? How do you start service? What is your `Intent` to stop a service?

Comment: I know that my service is not killed because onDestroy is not called

Comment: Then investigate your code once again. It simply impossible that `stopService` would not stop a service. If so, you're definitely using binding somewhere, completely ignorant to this very fact. Make sure you return `null` in service's `onBind()` (as it is not intended for binding). And **of course**, make sure your listener works as expected, that is, *it triggers the* `stopService(..)` code